# Check if next value in row is the same based on conditions python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
country  question    year   value
   1      a1          2017     Y
   1      a1          2018     Y
   1      a1          2019     N
   1      a2          2017     N
   1      a2          2018     N
   1      a2          2019     Y
   2      a1          2017     Y
   2      a1          2018     Nan
   2      a1          2019     Y
   2      a2          2017     Y
   2      a2          2018     N
   2      a2          2019     Y
   3      a1          2017     Y
   3      a1          2018     N
   3      a1          2019     Y
   3      a2          2017     Y
   3      a2          2018     Y
   3      a2          2019     Y
```

I want to find where the value from the previous year does not match the value from the next year. I have tried using shift but it doesn't give me what I want.
This is how far I've gotten:

```
 country = all_data['country']
 question = all_data['question']
 value = all_data['value']

 for i in range(len(country)):
     if(country[i] == country[i+1] && question[i] == question[i+1]):
```

Desired output:

```
country  question    year   value      match
   1      a1          2017     Y        
   1      a1          2018     Y         T
   1      a1          2019     N         F
   1      a2          2017     N         
   1      a2          2018     N         T
   1      a2          2019     Y         F
   2      a1          2017     Y           
   2      a1          2018     Nan       F
   2      a1          2019     Y         F
   2      a2          2017     Y      
   2      a2          2018     N         F
   2      a2          2019     Y         F
   3      a1          2017     Y         
   3      a1          2018     N         F
   3      a1          2019     Y         F
   3      a2          2017     Y 
   3      a2          2018     Y         T
   3      a2          2019     Y         T
```

Thank you for any suggestions!!

Comment: Why are there some gaps in the desired `match` column?

Comment: Because the rows aren't in order of year after year I guess.

Comment: @mpatil Could you please provide example for input? in such way I'll be able to construct the dataframe by my-self easily?

Comment: @MustafaAydın the gaps are when the country/question changes. So if it's the first year for the given country and answer then I don't want it to be as False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `groupby` with `shift` then `mask` the first item with `duplicated`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(['country','question']).value.shift().\
                   eq(df.value).mask(~df[['country','question']].duplicated(),'')
Out[435]: 
0          
1      True
2     False
3          
4      True
5     False
6          
7     False
8     False
9          
10    False
11    False
12         
13    False
14    False
15         
16     True
17     True
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us `group` the dataframe on `country` and `question` then `shift` the column `value` one unit downwards, finally compare the shifted `value` column with the `value` column from original dataframe to create a boolean mask.

```
s = df.groupby(['country', 'question'])['value'].shift()
df['match'] = df['value'].eq(s).mask(s.isna(), '')
```

---

```
    country question  year value  match
0         1       a1  2017     Y       
1         1       a1  2018     Y   True
2         1       a1  2019     N  False
3         1       a2  2017     N       
4         1       a2  2018     N   True
5         1       a2  2019     Y  False
6         2       a1  2017     Y       
7         2       a1  2018   Nan  False
8         2       a1  2019     Y  False
9         2       a2  2017     Y       
10        2       a2  2018     N  False
11        2       a2  2019     Y  False
12        3       a1  2017     Y       
13        3       a1  2018     N  False
14        3       a1  2019     Y  False
15        3       a2  2017     Y       
16        3       a2  2018     Y   True
17        3       a2  2019     Y   True
```